# How to resolve parent to child relationship with AppSync

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync, vtl

I have schema looking like below

```
type Post {
    id: ID!
    creator: String!
    createdAt: String!
    like: Int!
    dislike: Int!
    frozen: Boolean!
    revisions:[PostRevision!]
}

type PostRevision {
    id: ID!
    post: Post!
    content: String!
    author: String!
    createdAt: String!
}
type Mutation {
    createPost(postInput: CreatePostInput!): Post
}
```

I would like to be able to batch insert Post and PostRevision at the same time when i run createPost mutation; however, VTL is giving me a much of hard time.

I have tried below

```
## Variable Declarations
#set($postId = $util.autoId())
#set($postList = [])
#set($postRevisionList = [])
#set($post = {})
#set($revision = {})

## Initialize Post object
$util.qr($post.put("creator", $ctx.args.postInput.author))
$util.qr($post.put("id", $postId))
$util.qr($post.put("createdAt", $util.time.nowEpochMilliSeconds()))
$util.qr($post.put("like", 0))
$util.qr($post.put("dislike", 0))
$util.qr($post.put("frozen", false))

## Initialize PostRevision object
$util.qr($revision.put("id", $util.autoId()))
$util.qr($revision.put("author", $ctx.args.postInput.author))
$util.qr($revision.put("post", $postId))
$util.qr($revision.put("content", $ctx.args.postInput.content))
$util.qr($revision.put("createdAt", $util.time.nowEpochMilliSeconds()))

## Listify objects
$postList.add($post)
$postRevisionList.add($revision)

{
    "version" : "2018-05-29",
    "operation" : "BatchPutItem",
    "tables" : {
        "WHISPR_DEV_PostTable": $util.toJson($postList),
        "WHISPR_DEV_PostRevisionTable": $util.toJson($postRevisionList)
    }
}
```

So basically I am reconstructing the document in the resolver of createPost so that I can add `Post` then also add `ID` of the post to `postReivision` However when I run below code

```
mutation insertPost{
  createPost(postInput:{
    creator:"name"
    content:"value"
  }){
    id
  }
}
```

I get following error

```
{
  "data": {
    "createPost": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "path": [
        "createPost"
      ],
      "data": null,
      "errorType": "MappingTemplate",
      "errorInfo": null,
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3,
          "sourceName": null
        }
      ],
      "message": "Expected JSON object but got BOOLEAN instead."
    }
  ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

I know it would be easier to resolve with lambda function but I do not want to double up the cost for no reason. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a call to **$util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson** which is causing AppSync to try to put plain JSON objects into DynamoDB when DynamoDB requires a DynamoDB specific input structure where each attribute instead of being a plain string like "hello world!" is an object { "S": "hello world!" }. The **$util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson** helper handles this for you for convenience. Can you please try adding the **toDynamoDBJson()** to these lines:

```
## Listify objects
$postList.add($util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($post))
$postRevisionList.add($util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($revision))
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

If anyone still needs the answer for this (this question is still the #1 google hit for the mentioned error message):

The problem is the return value of the add() method, which returns a boolean value.

To fix this, just wrap the add() methods into `$util.qr`, as you are already doing for the put() methods:

```
$util.qr(($postList.add($post))
$util.qr(($postRevisionList.add($revision))
```